# How to get PowerShell to not dismiss the active selection after 'ctrl+c'

Tags: powershell

Initially I thought this was to do with Windows Terminal, So I asked the Windows Terminal team and the issue [Copy text without dismissing the selection #15371](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/15371)  was created and eventually completed:
You can now pass `dismissSelection` as an argument to the `Copy`  action, so that when a copy is performed the selection is not discarded:

```
{
    "command": 
    {
         "action": "copy",
         "singleLine": false,
         "dismissSelection": false
    },
    "keys": "ctrl+c"
},
```

But then I learnt this has no effect on the PowerShell Shell host itself, PowerShell will still dismiss selections, upon pressing `ctrl`+ `c`.

I need this functionality in place for a few small programs, built with AutoHotkey. These programs work fine everywhere else but on the Terminal. Its just standard Clipboard manipulations stuff that makes my disability and life easy.